# Tensorboard: why is family name prefixed twice?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm using `tf.summary.histogram(var_name, var, family='my_family')` to log a histogram. In the tensorboard interface it appears as

```
my_family/my_family/var_name
```

Does anybody know what the logic is behind duplicating the family name?

It does seem intentional, as I find the following in  [tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/summary_op_util.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6612da89516247503f03ef76e974b51a434fb52e/tensorflow/python/ops/summary_op_util.py#L98) :

```py
# Use family name in the scope to ensure uniqueness of scope/tag.
scope_base_name = name if family is None else '{}/{}'.format(family, name)
with ops.name_scope(scope_base_name, default_name, values) as scope:
  if family is None:
    tag = scope.rstrip('/')
  else:
    # Prefix our scope with family again so it displays in the right tab.
    tag = '{}/{}'.format(family, scope.rstrip('/'))
```

The first time `family` is inserted in `scope_base_name = name if family is None else '{}/{}'.format(family, name)`, and the second time in `tag = '{}/{}'.format(family, scope.rstrip('/'))`, which according to the comments in the code was deliberate.

Answer (score 1):

I too was frustrated by this, but in the context of using tf.summary.scalar. I've resorted to using:

```
tf.summary.scalar('myfamily/myname', var)
```

Now the variables show up in Tensorboard without the duplication of the family name.

P.S. I would have made this a "comment" instead of an answer, but my reputation is too low.